# KnockoutJS how to bind textarea value property to function

Tags: knockout.js, textarea

I have simple `textarea` that i want to customize it's text(like add break-lines), that's what I have tried so far:

```
<textarea rows="5" data-bind="value: function(data) { SetDefaultValue(data); }" />
```

but I get nothing.

When checking the resulting HTML it doesn't find the value property and has no JavaScript errors. How can I bind `value` property of a `textarea` to function.

**[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YEp2V/1/)**

Comment: What error ? Could you make a fiddle ?

Comment: @Damien updated my question with demo

Comment: What should be the data in your `function(data)`?

Comment: @nemesv it should be data from my model like "firstName"..i updated the demo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<textarea rows="5" type="text" data-bind="value: SetValue(firstName)" />
```

and than in javascript:

```
function AppModel() {
this.firstName = "ebram";
this.lastName = "Tharwat";
this.SetValue = function (data) {
    //Do the processing over here
    return data.toUpperCase();
   }
}
ko.applyBindings(new AppModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is have a computed modifying your textarea value like so

```
<textarea rows="5" type="text" data-bind="value:textarea, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />

function AppModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.textarea = ko.observable('');

    self.SetValue = ko.computed(function(){
        self.textarea(self.textarea().toUpperCase());
    });

}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YEp2V/3/

Comment: thanks for answer, but i need the function to be executed when i pass the value, or bind the function to value property

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve. try to explain better

Comment: i have value coming from the viewmodel that i want to make processing on it before passing it as the value.. this processing is depending on other properties of that viewmodel

Comment: can't you do that processing inside the `computed`?

Comment: textarea does not need a type attribute